# How to hide decrement button for past month?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, angular-bootstrap-calendar

Previous month button should be hidden with `ng-show="isPastMonth(calendarDate)"` for past month form the current month.

Is there any option in the **angular-bootstrap-calendar** to hide `decrement="calendarView"` for past months ?

```
<button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  mwl-date-modifier
  date="vm.viewDate"
  decrement="vm.calendarView">
  Previous
</button>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LE4F4U7AnnD3tjM9ZH4G?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
vm.previousMonth = angular.copy((vm.viewDate.getFullYear() * 12) + vm.viewDate.getMonth()) - 1;

//To get the previous month then to disable using this condition

ng-disabled="vm.previousMonth === ((vm.viewDate.getFullYear() * 12) + vm.viewDate.getMonth()) - 1"
```

Check it here
http://plnkr.co/edit/NFI6tq?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean hide the button with `ng-show`

Comment: You can use same condition with ng-hide